# Extract Cell Information from In-Sight Explorer (Cognex) with Android

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I was wondering how i can do that, i have the c# sdk, i *believe* i can use this for Xamarin also and i know that with native commands i can communicate but im not very sure how i connect all the pieces together for xamarin.

[Here are the commands.](https://www.scribd.com/document/349308773/Native-Mode-Commands)

Should i use telnet or serial communication? can someone give me a simple example of serial communication?

I have tried this https://github.com/mik3y/usb-serial-for-android for serial commection but it seems my mobile doesnt support it. i dont know how i can run telnet commands

Answer (score 1):

You won't be able to use the In-Sight SDK on Android, but you can use Native Mode Commands since native mode commands are simply text commands and responses sent over either Ethernet (telnet) or serial.

[Example Xamarin socket client application](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/System.Net.Sockets.Socket/)

Comment: can i use this? https://components.xamarin.com/view/socketioclientdotnet